# Text in footer won't show, paragraph won't wrap, and image flows above navigation bar

Tags: html, css

http://i.imgur.com/sTt59s4.png

Problem #1: Text in footer disappeared. Just randomly noticed while I was busy aligning other elements that the text in my footer was gone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/clY6i.jpg

Problem #2: Paragraph won't wrap. If I hadn't put `display: inline` the text would disappear completely.

Problem #3: Images float on top of my nav bar. When I scroll down, the images pass on top of the bar and it looks weird.

Feel free to correct my coding in general. I am a noob. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>BIKES & BITES | ABOUT</title>

    <link href="styles/Hortaleza-Kyla-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700italic,900italic,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
```

```
<header>

    <section id="title-slogan">

        <h1>BIKES & BITES</h1>
        <p>EAT • BIKE • LOVE</p>

    </section>

    <nav id="main-nav">

        <ul>
            <li><img src="index-images/B&B-logo.png" id="logo"></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="02-about.html" class="about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="03-adventures.html" class="adventures">ADVENTURES</a></li>
            <li><a href="04-hungry.html" class="hungry">HUNGRY?</a></li>
            <li><a href="05-calendar.html" class="calendar">CALENDAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="06-contact.html" class="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

</header>

<section id="main-content">

        <h1>ABOUT</h1>

    <section id="about-bb">

        <img src="02-about-images/B&B-logo2.png">

        <p id="desc"><b>BIKES & BITES</b> brings you cycling and food all wrapped into one delicious burrito. It’s for anyone, everyone; it’s for people like you! People who love health and at the same time, love good food. Whether you’re just thinking of buying a bike, a total newbie, or even a pro, we welcome everyone to the community. We're just here to have a good time!

        <b>BIKES & BITES</b> aims to share with its readers the beauty and enjoyment of cycling, with the help of the natural beauty of the Philippines. It aims to encourage others to try taking up the sport—or any sport for that matter—and at the same time a healthy lifestyle (but still be able to eat what you want!). <b>BIKES & BITES</b> will provide you with routes, recipes, and many more, to help you with every aspect of your cycling life.</p>

    </section>

    <section id="about-creator">
        <img src="02-about-images/02-about-profile.png">
        <p><h3>Kyla Hortaleza</h3>
        <i>Founder and Editor</i><br><br>
        Despite being an avid cyclist and part-time duathlete, Kyla Hortaleza is currently an Interdisciplinary Studies major in Ateneo de Manila University. She is 22-years-old and has no experience of writing a serious blog whatsoever, but finds delight in sharing her experiences to others through her pictures. She believes in the power of juicing and the power of carbohydrates (no to fad diets but yes to moderation!). She loves promoting cycling and believes that it is the sport that anyone can try and enjoy regularly.</p>

    </section>

</section>

<footer>
    <p>Created by Kyla Hortaleza | 2015</p>
</footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: auto;
background: #fdedf1;
padding-top: 80px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
} 

#aboutpage #main-content #about-bb p {
    display: inline;
}

#aboutpage #main-content {
    overflow: scroll;
}

#aboutpage #main-content p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 200px;
}

#aboutpage #main-content img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#aboutpage #main-nav a.about {
    color: #f8bfcd; 
}

#aboutpage #main-nav a.about:hover {
    color: #ccf0e2; 
}

#aboutpage #main-content #about-bb {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 75px 0px 75px 200px;
}

#aboutpage #main-content #about-creator {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 75px 0px 75px 75px;
}

#aboutpage #main-content #about-creator img {
    padding-left: 45px;
}

#main-content h1 {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body #title-slogan h1, p {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -21px;
}

body #title-slogan-hungry h1, p {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -194px;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    top: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#main-nav {
    background: white;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 70px;
}

#main-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-variant-caps: all-small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#main-nav a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
    color: #ccf0e2;
}

footer p {
    background: black;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

from

```
 body #title-slogan h1, p 
body #title-slogan-hungry h1, p
```

It should look like this now:

```
body #title-slogan h1, p {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -21px;
}

body #title-slogan-hungry h1 {
    text-indent: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -194px;
    padding: 0;
```

Oh, and you've forgotten opening a `<body>` tag before header starts.

Comment: currently using company's laptop to edit and is locked down. I've edited by seeing the text only. Do let me know if anything else is wrong.
I'm using IE 9 btw.

Comment: OH MY GOD IT'S FINALLY NORMAL AGAIN

Comment: I don't know how I could possibly thank you. You just saved my life. Seriously. :(

Comment: No problem :) just give an upvote and accepted answer will do! HTML is my passion!